# Returning an individual Cell address within a range

Tags: excel, vba

Long story short, I am trying to compare two ranges against each other. In doing so I am trying to return an individual cell address dependant on its content. In this case if the cell contains "AL" it will return me the address of that cell in a msgbox for now.

I cannot figure out how to return the individual cell address rather than the whole range.

```
For Each inRng In Range(MyRange1)
    MsgBox Range(MyRange1).Cells.Address
Next
```

So for now I just want this to display each individual cell address as it goes through the range rather than this:

[image: Range return]

Comment: How about `MsgBox inRng.Address`?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Been staring at that bit of code for ages.... not realising I had put the wrong range in there !